# SQLite return dataset where top 4 aggregated records are single rows and rest records are agrageted as one row

Tags: sql, sqlite

Sorry for not very good title but maybe someone can help me to understand how to write query using sqlite. So I have table where stored transactions which are assigned to some category I want to sum amount group by category and get top 4 rows, rest records have to be summed with grouping and returned as one row

| id | amount | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | shopping |
| 2 | 40 | mortgage |
| 3 | 15 | shopping |
| 4 | 10 | insurance |
| 5 | 5 | entertainment |
| 6 | 8 | some category 1 |
| 7 | 10 | some category 2 |

And I need result like this

| Category | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Mortgage | 40 |
| Shopping | 25 |
| Insurance | 10 |
| some category 2 | 10 |
| others | 13 |

So how you can see I sum amount of each category and order them after 4th record I sum rest and return as single record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUM()` aggregation and `ROW_NUMBER()` window function in order to filter the Category `others` such as

```
WITH t AS
(
 SELECT Category, SUM(Amount) AS sum
   FROM tab
  GROUP BY Category
), t1 AS
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sum DESC ) AS dr
  FROM t
)
SELECT Category, sum AS Amount FROM t1 WHERE dr <= 4
UNION ALL
SELECT 'others', SUM(sum) FROM t1 WHERE dr  > 4
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4727f651ebfe1dd3b5b42905996ac6f8)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks!It works you know I was waiting for answer and did something like you advice :D was testing performance looks like it is good

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with 2 levels of aggregation and `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT category, SUM(amount) amount
FROM (
  SELECT CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC) <= 4 THEN category ELSE 'others' END category, 
         SUM(amount) amount
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY category
) 
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY category = 'others', amount DESC
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d21517436a8b2b4ec927c691ab5c4fb2).
Results:

| category | amount |
| --- | --- |
| mortgage | 40 |
| shopping | 25 |
| insurance | 10 |
| some category 2 | 10 |
| others | 13 |